# Como alterar a cor do background de um slider do plugin bootstrap-slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

estou trabalhando com [bootstrap-slider](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider) e quero fazer com que o *slider* ao ser arrastado, e ter o seu valor entre determinado intervalo de número (utilizo `onChange`), modificar a cor do background da barra de seleção. Já consegui fazer a modificação da borda, mas a barra de seleção em si eu não consegui encontrar uma forma com `jQuery`.

O código :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ex13").slider({
    id: "slider12a",
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    ticks: [0, 25, 50, 75, 100],
    ticks_snap_bounds: 5,
    ticks_labels: ['', '', '', '', ''],
    value: 0
  });




});

function setarCorSlider(tamanho) {

  if (tamanho < 24) {
    document.getElementById('slider12a').style.background = "red"; //altera a borda, mas pelo meu entendimento se eu apelidei o slider 'ex13' de id: 'slider12a', deveria alterar tudo e não apenas a borda 

    //tentei usar jQuery para alterar a cor da classe slider-selection, mas não funcionou
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.slider-selection').css('background: red');
    });
     //ou
    $('.slider-selection').css('background: red'); //também testei assim e não funcionou
  } else if (tamanho > 25 && tamanho < 74) {
    document.getElementById('slider12a').style.background = "yellow";
  } else if (tamanho > 75) {
    document.getElementById('slider12a').style.background = "green";
  }
}
```

```css
#slider12a .slider-selection {
  background: #DDD; //*Inicialmente a barra possui o background da barra azul, a medida que vai arrastando ela*
}
```

```html
<link href="http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/css/bootstrap-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/dependencies/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/dependencies/js/modernizr.js" />


<input id="ex13" type="text" data-slider-ticks="[0, 25, 50, 75, 100]" data-slider-ticks-snap-bounds="5" onchange="setarCorSlider(this.value)" />

<script type='text/javascript' src="http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/dependencies/js/jquery.min.js" />
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/js/bootstrap-slider.js" />
<!-- coloquem o JavaScript do código aqui -->
```

Comment: Ps.: Quem tiver reputação superior a 300, indico criar uma tag para essa pergunta chamada: bootstrap-slider, pode ajudar futuras dúvidas.

Comment: Coloca `background: red!important`. **!important** no caso. `$('.slider-selection').css('background: red!important');`

Comment: @DiegoSouza obrigado pela dica, mas alto-priorizar o elemento  dentro do `jQuery` também não funcionou. Continua com `#DDD`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui! Na verdade o erro estava na notação `jQuery` o correto é passar os dois parâmetros separados, 'background-color' e em seguida o parâmetro com o `value` da cor.

```
$('#slider12a .slider-selection').css('background-color','#F55');
```

E o outro problema é que além de setar o código é necessário que você remova o `background-image`, pois o `bootstrap-slider` utiliza imagem no seu `CSS` `bootstrap-slider.css` por isso, o plano de fundo "não aparecia", pois a imagem estava "por cima".

Segue código:

```
function setarCorSlider(tamanho){

        if (tamanho<24){
                $('#slider12a .slider-selection').css('background-image','none');
                $('#slider12a .slider-selection').css('background-color','#F55');
        }
        else if (tamanho>25 && tamanho<74){
            $('#slider12a .slider-selection').css('background-image','none');
            $('#slider12a .slider-selection').css('background-color','#FFA477');            
        }
        else if (tamanho>75){
            $('#slider12a .slider-selection').css('background-image','none');
            $('#slider12a .slider-selection').css('background-color','#93FF93');
        }

    }
```

Além disso, para futuros usuários que possam ter esse problema, a classe que trata da folha de estilo da "bolinha que arrasta" ou em tradução literal "carrapato (`track`)" é justamente a `.slider-track`

Answer (score -1):

A classe na qual muda a cor do background é essa aqui:

`slider-track-high`.

Coloque isso dentro da função `setarCorSlider`.
`$('.slider-track-high').css('background-color', 'red');`

E tire de dentro do `$(document).ready()`, não tem necessidade.

Comment: É verdade, o `slider-track-high` é a cor "padrão" do background do slider, ou seja, o preenchimento "completo" "100%" da barra, mas eu não quero alterar o background dela a medida que for arrastado o seletor, e sim alterar a cor do próprio seletor. No exemplo 12 (http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/ ) isso que falastes, mas não consegui mudar a cor do seletor, ou seja, identificar a classe que trata isso (acho que é a slider-selection), o comando que indicastes não funcionou nem dentro nem fora do ...ready(), talvez a classe realmente seja `.slider-selection` mas o jQuery não tá funcionando.

Comment: Sabes o que está acontecendo que o meu comando jQuery pra atualizar o background de uma classe não está funcionando? Já tentei entrar no próprio `js` do add-on pra ver se conseguia alterar algo no código dele mas está muio complexo.